# How to Pass Argument as Object for call WCF DataContract

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

l
     **- This My Interface Class For WCFSeviceLibrary**

In This interface class IService1 in declare OperationContract as one ObjectClass Type Method.

And Create this ObjectClass Class For Set Type. as Ganeric.

```
    public interface IService1
        {               
             [OperationContract]
             ObjectClass SetDataUsingDataContract(ObjectClass data); 
        }
    [DataContract]
        public class ObjectClass
        {
            string name;
            string address;
            string emailid;
            double contactno;
            [DataMember]
            public string Name
            {
                set { name = value; }
                get { return name; }
            }

            [DataMember]
            public string Address
            {
                set { address = value; }
                get { return address; }
            }

            [DataMember]
            public string EmailId
            {
                set { emailid = value; }
                get { return emailid; }
            }

            [DataMember]
            public double ContactNO
            {
                set { contactno = value; }
                get { return contactno; }
            }

        }
```

Service.cs File
In This Class Implimate

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
 public ObjectClass SetDataUsingDataContract(ObjectClass data)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Pavan\WCF_Practice\WcfServiceSample\WebApplicationvc\App_Data\WCFDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WCFTBL (Name, Address, ContactNo, EmailID) VALUES ('"+data.Name+"','"+data.Address+"','"+data.ContactNO+"','"+data.EmailId+"')",conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return data;
        }
}
```

This My Btn_Click Class of WebApplication Page

```
 protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client srv = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();


            srv.SetDataUsingDataContract();

}
```

I Dont Know How To Set Argument Of srv.SetDataUsingDataContract() method.

**AppConfig File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibraryforADD.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibraryforADD.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibraryforADD/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibraryforADD.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceLibraryforADD.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can't you create an `ObjectClass` instance?

Comment: @AmiramKorach **I had try as akton suggest me but still getting error.**
please Find Error in akton Answer.

Comment: Just an observation but you are really looking to get hacked.  Your SQL just takes whatever a user types in and strings it together: opening you up to a SQL injection attack.  Solve this by using SQL parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `ObjectClass` instance and pass it as an argument to `SetDataUsingDataContract`. For example:

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ServiceReference1.Service1Client srv = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

     ObjectClass objectClass = new ObjectClass();
     // Set properties 
     srv.SetDataUsingDataContract(objectClass);
}
```

The client generation code should have created an `ObjectClass` class for the caller to reference.

Comment: I try above code but getting Following Error. `The best overloaded method match for 'WebApplicationvc.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.SetDataUsingDataContract(WebApplicationvc.ServiceReference1.ObjectClass)' has some invalid arguments`
and `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'WebApplicationvc.ObjectClass' to 'WebApplicationvc.ServiceReference1.ObjectClass'
`

Comment: You probably have the `ObjectClass` defined twice in client. One that you wrote yourself and the other that was generated by adding the service reference.

Comment: @PavanVParekh Reference the version of ObjectClass in the generated client (WebApplicationvc.ServiceReference1.ObjectClass) instead. If you have repeated the definition, remove it from WebApplication. You can have two classes with the same name but, internally, they are still different even if they share the same members.

Comment: @akton and @AmiramKorach thank you yes done with remove duplicate object class from web application but now i am getting following error runtime from `Service1Client srv = new Service1Client();` **Runtime error is**
An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Comment: @Amiram Korach I had check config file. **My Appconfig file Two endpoint (1 is default and 2 is for mex)**  Please look at my question I had add Appconfig Code.

Comment: You added the service config. Add the client config.

Comment: @Amiram Korach Thank You So Much.
I Deleted Duplicate Endpoint From Web.Config So now Application run successfully.